# Is there some way to simplify access to the first member of a group in a LINQ GroupBy query?

Tags: linq, group-by, linq-to-entities

I have the following LINQ statement that collects the results by the Site:

```
        var groupedSites = ungroupedSites.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(_ => _.s.SiteUid)
                    .Select(g => new MySites {
                            Title = g.First().sd.Title,
                            Classification = g.First().s.Classification,
                            Service = g.First().p.ServiceGateway,
                                   etc.
                        });
```

There are a dozen other properties in the initializer for 'MySites' that use g.First().  Is there some better way (than g.First()) that I can access the first item of the group?  Ideally, it would be nice to have a variable:

```
var first = g.first()
```

And use that.

Comment: Yes, use query syntax and `let`.

Comment: @GertArnold Or translate query syntax `let` to fluent syntax by using `Select` to create a new anonymous type.

Comment: Yes, but `let` has the look & feel of a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by additional `Select`:

```cs
var groupedSites = ungroupedSites.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(_ => _.s.SiteUid)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .Select(f => new MySites {
            Title = f.sd.Title,
            Classification = f.s.Classification,
            Service = f.p.ServiceGateway,
                    etc.
    });
```